# What does "Drama holds a mirror up to life" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

It's a quote by Roger Ebert.

> Drama holds a mirror up to life, but needn't reproduce it.

I think I get a vague idea of what he is trying to convey, but the exact picture/meaning eludes my grasp.

Comment: It's figurative -- a metaphor of sorts.  A couple of nights ago I saw the play "The Adams Family" (not technically a drama, but close enough), and, while it in no way reproduces "life" as we know it, it did serve to draw attention to several aspects of life and human relations which otherwise one might not notice.

Comment: @HotLicks I think I've got it now. It just clicked after I read your comment and read the quote again, out loud. I am tempted to write an answer, but don't know if I am supposed to as the OP, or should I just delete the question?

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question. https://english.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Hello, Deansue. As @user 159691 articulately expresses: '[S]orry, but in this site we deal with specific language issues (grammar, usage, meaning [of standard words and expressions] etc.) Interpretations of song lyrics, poetry or **other forms of writing** are subject to personal interpretations and personal preferences. See here for more: english.stackexchange.com/help.' This would be appropriate on WritersSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[“Drama holds a mirror up to life, but it needn’t reproduce it.”](https://ofviceandpen.wordpress.com/2014/07/06/of-death-and-roger-ebert/)
a blog on Roger Ebert

> "What is it about the medium of film that has such a hold on us, an
>   exponential, unexplainable grip, a reverence for story? Life itself ...

and more at the link.

Answer (score 0):

Drama has been described as "minds in conflict and hearts breaking," which pretty much covers 90 percent of life. Drama reflects the lives we lead, thus a mirror.